# How to notify database change in BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite

There's a ListView in a fragment, I want it to show some messages downloaded from the server(json arrays) every time the fragment is created. After downloading I put the messages into a sqlite database, and then reveal the messages in that listView, using **BaseAdapter**.

But I have to know what getCount() in BaseAdapter should return before setAdapter(); but downloading messages needs time, I won't know the count until the messages are downloaded.

So I put a progress bar in the fragment and try to start another fragment and setAdapter() after the messages are downloaded and written into the database. The Question is how can I know when the messages are downloaded and written to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an AsyncTask

```
class DownLoadMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //here you download your message

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

       // and here you set your adapter

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```